# openlayers trigger hover event

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, vector, features, events

I have a bunch of tracks on screen in a vector layer. I used some hover and select styles in the layer styleMap and these styles are properly triggered by:

```
    var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(tbTrack.vector, {
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true,
        renderIntent: "hover",
    });

    var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(tbTrack.vector,
        {clickout: true, renderIntent: "select"}
    );

    tbMap.map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
    tbMap.map.addControl(selectCtrl);

    highlightCtrl.activate();
    selectCtrl.activate()
```

All these tracks are listed in a table under the map. I want to trigger the corresponding hover and select styles for a track if I click or hover on them in the table. How to do this?
I allready have the coupling between the table and the lines, I just don't know the right way to trigger the hover or select events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered before on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832029/how-to-select-a-feature-programmatically-on-a-vector-layer-in-openlayers